# Searching for items in JSON

Tags: angular

I have a Web application that consumes data from another Web service and they are in JSON format. I subscribed the data as `results[]` and I can access each of field by getting each of index in html, for example, `{{results?.ABC.D[0].Name[0]}}` and it returns `Susan`. (Please refer to the data sample below).

What I want to do is to search in `results` to find out `Name` and return `G`. Basically, I would like to acquire `G`'s when they are in a same array `D` with `Name`.

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "D": [
            {
                "Name": [ "Susan" ],
                "F": [ "School_0" ],
                "G": [ "14" ]
            },
            {
                "Name": [ "Lydia" ],
                "F": [ "School_1" ],
                "G": [ "284" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your problem :(  you want to get g, if e is in d ?

Comment: I just updated naming the object. I need to get a specific G, but not Name. I need to point to Name in order to get G. Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you want to get this in your Typescript Code or in Html code ?

Comment: `return results.ABC.D.filter(d => d.Name[0] === 'Susan').map(d => d.G)`? Choosing meaningful names and types for your attributes would make things much easier.

Comment: I looked it up and didn't get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

Suppose that the data sample we have is the following:

```
 let dataSample =
      {
        "ABC": {
          "D": [
            {
              "Name": [
                "Susan",
                "Sophia"
              ],
              "F": [
                "School_0"
              ],
              "G": [
                "14"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Name": [
                "Lydia"
              ],

              "F": [
                "School_1"
              ],
              "G": [
                "284"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

if you want to iterate through all Name[ ], then you should also find the index of the name you want inside of the "Name" array and retrieve it, and then find the index of the "D" that contains that retrieved name. Like this:

```
    let names = ["Sophia", "Susan", "Lydia"];

    names.forEach(function(name) {
    this.findNameG(name)
    })

    function findNameG(nameToFind: String) {        
    let index = dataSample.ABC.D.findIndex(d => d.Name[d.Name.findIndex(name => name === nameToFind)]);
    console.log(dataSample.ABC.D[index].G);
}
```

So you need to find the index of the name first, and the return the value of G at that index.

**Please consider that this is case sensitive, if you want to make it other wise you should use toLowerCase() or toUpperCase() methods for both source and target.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to iterate through all Name[ ]

Comment: It works now, but how should I do this for multiple Names? So I have specific given Names and need to search for them and display respective Gs

Comment: So you place the above code in a function, and then loop for the specific given names and execute the function for each name individually.

Comment: Declare the function the way it fits your environment, I am just writing a syntax :)

Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Comment: got it, but would it go through and retrieve all IDs for Names I defined? You have the === "Susan" there

Comment: Sorry forgot to change that, check now

Comment: Hi R.AbuBarker, Thanks for the help.. last thing. Why am I getting property 'findLastValue' does not exist on type void? res is where I get JSON object from service. Please refer to updated post.

Comment: Your function is inside of ngOnInit, please move it outside and the call it like this:

this.findLastValue(name);

Comment: Also don't forget to fix your "names" array declaration.

from this: let names = ["Suan, Mike"];
to this: let names = ["Suan", "Mike"];

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to return G , in condition you have Name[0] Value ? 
In this case :

```
 {{results?.ABC.D[0].Name[0] ? results?.ABC.D[0].G : '' }}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to go through all D[ ]

Comment: Let me understand , You want to get all the G's of all the D Array elements, IF there's a name in the D element ?

Comment: only for specific D[]s while iterating D[]. Then I want to get some elements in D, in this case G.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
jsonData = {
"ABC":{
   "D":[
      {
         "Name":[
            "Susan"
         ],
         "F":[
            "School_0"
         ],
         "G":[
            "14"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Name":[
            "Lydia"
         ],

         "F":[
            "School_1"
         ],
         "G":[
            "284"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
}
```

You can check like this, but i am sure there must be a simple solution

```
for (var key1 in this.jsonData) {
  if (this.jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key1)) {
      for (var key2 in this.jsonData[key1]){
        if (this.jsonData[key1].hasOwnProperty(key2)){
          if(key2 == "D"){
            for (var key3 in this.jsonData[key1][key2]){
              if (this.jsonData[key1][key2].hasOwnProperty(key3)){
                if(this.jsonData[key1][key2][key3]["Name"][0] == "Susan"){
                  console.log(this.jsonData[key1][key2][key3]["G"][0])
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is hasOwnProperty?

Comment: this question has a brief explanation about it  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)